# Make height of the carousel same as the height of the image, ignoring the margin of the image

Tags: html, css, ng-bootstrap

I am using `ngb-carousel` as mentioned in documentation here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel

**Code:**

In app.ts:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ngbd-carousel-basic></ngbd-carousel-basic>
</div>
```

In carousel-basic.html:

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" alt="Random second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" alt="Random third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

In carousel-basic.css:

```
img {
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

ngb-carousel {
  background-color: black;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Plunk:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/aph3NqBCEuVGsxkWbco4?p=preview

I want to make the height of the carousel same as the height of the image, ignoring the margins used by the image.

So, In short, black parts shown in above image should not appear and also the headings and indicators should move on the image.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I don't want 100% height. I want  to maintain the aspect ratio between height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may little complicated if don't want to remove margin:auto and also not want to fix the height.Better see this example of

[bootstrap carousel example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h)

Comment: You are interpreting me somewhat wrong. I am not interested in margin. But I don't want to fixed height of Image. I want that Image should maintain the aspect ration between its width and height. Though I will just take a look at the example provided by you.

Comment: this answer having your solution but for container item img, they are not using margin.

Comment: This works well for my case. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change css then update below part of css.

```
img[_ngcontent-c0] {
    /* margin: auto; */
    height: 300px; /* You can change as you need */
    /* width: 100%; */
    object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to specify height, because I want to maintain aspect ratio of the original Image. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Give height to `carousel-item` which should be equal to your image height. It will work fine

Comment: How can I do that using css? Because height of the image is set to auto.

Comment: Or give your image height: 100%.

Comment: I don't want 100% height. I want to maintain the aspect ratio between height and width.

Comment: I don't think there will be any other solution.